# window.imagePicker.getPictures not working in Phonegap

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I am working on an Android app where I have to select multiple images from gallery.

I am using imagepicker in my code to select the image from gallery

```
$scope.selImages = function() {

    window.imagePicker.getPictures(
        function(results) {

            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                console.log('Image URI: ' + results[i]);
                $scope.images.push(results[i]);
            }
            if(!$scope.$$phase) {
                $scope.$apply();
            }
        }, function (error) {
            console.log('Error: ' + error);
        }
    );

};
```

}])

which is not working. I don't know what is the issue is

I have installed following plugins in my app
 cordova-plugin-device
 cordova-plugin-camera
 cordova-plugin-media-capture
 cordova-plugin-file-transfer

please Help,

Answer (score -1):

I found out that using window.plugins.imagePicker instead of windows.imagePicker solves this issue, perhaps this fallback applies for other plugins as well.